# Find implicit value by abstract type member

Tags: scala, implicits, abstract-type

With a type like `trait A[T]`, finding an implicit in scope is simply `implicitly[A[SomeType]]`

Can this be done and, if so, how is this done where the type-parameter is replaced with an abstract type member, like in `trait A { type T }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
implicitly[A { type T = Int }
```

but you risk to lose precision:

```
scala> trait Foo { type T ; val t: T }
defined trait Foo

scala> implicit val intFoo: Foo { type T = Int } = new Foo { type T = Int ; val t = 23 }
intFoo: Foo{type T = Int} = $anon$1@6067b682

scala> implicitly[Foo].t // implicitly loses precision
res0: Foo#T = 23
```

To solve this problem, you can use [the newly introduced `the` method](https://gist.github.com/milessabin/8833a1dbf7e8245b30f8), from the `shapeless` library (from which I've take the example above)

```
scala> the[Foo].t // the retains it
res1: Int = 23

scala> the[Foo].t+13
res2: Int = 36
```

Comment: `the` is great, but `implicitly[Foo { type T = Int }]` accomplishes the same thing, and is more directly parallel to the type parameter case.

Comment: right, this is probably and overekill, but I jusy wanted to point out the risk and suggest an alternative :)

Answer (score 1):

I just realized this can be done with `implicitly[A { type T = SomeType }]`